# How do I return specific string value from webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to return following JSON, but I missed the syntax. How can I correct it?

In my HomeController.cs,

```
If (result.IsUserActive) return JSON { “UserStatus” : “Active” }
```

How can I return value `“UserStatus” : “Active”` In Get method of webapi?

It must be like something:

```
[HttpGet]
        
        public IHttpActionResult GetUserStatus(int id)
        {
           
            var result = GetStatus(id);    
            if (result.IsUserActive)
            {
                return json ({ “UserStatus” : “Active” });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return the Json like:

```
var result = new {UserStatus="Active" };
return Ok(result);
```

Comment: if (result.IsUserActive)
 {
     var status = new { UserStatus = "Active" };
      return ok(status);
  }

This solution is for Web Api 2.

Comment: You can also use return Json(status);

Returning Json() always returns HTTP 200 and the result in JSON format, no matter what format is in the Accept header of the incoming request.

Returning Ok() returns HTTP 200, but the result will be formatted based on what was specified in the Accept request header.